# C# security - LinkDemand or SecurityCritical or any explanation?

Tags: c#, .net, security, fxcop, code-access-security

I have run security check on my application, and got the following warning:

> 'Parser.GenerateJeffpReport(string)' calls into 'Process.Start()'
>   which has a LinkDemand. By making this call, 'Process.Start()' is
>   indirectly exposed to user code. Review the following call stack that
>   might expose a way to circumvent security protection:

I have googled it, and found this question:

[what does this security warning mean (.Net Process class)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147220/what-does-this-security-warning-mean-net-process-class)

I tried to do as the recomended answer, i.e. set my method with:

```
[PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Name="FullTrust")]
```

However, I got the following warning:

> Microsoft.Security : 'Parser.ParseJeff(string)' is protected with a
>   LinkDemand for 'PermissionSetAttribute'.  In the level 2 security rule
>   set, it should be protected by being security critical instead. 
>   Remove the LinkDemand and mark 'Parser.ParseJeff(string)' security
>   critical.

What shall I do? What is the meaning of all of it anyway? why is it a security issue? I didn't found microsoft documentation at ths topic helpfull at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
[PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Name="FullTrust")]
```

with

[[SecurityCritical](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securitycriticalattribute.aspx)]

> The SecurityCriticalAttribute is equivalent to a link demand for full
>   trust. A type or member marked with the SecurityCriticalAttribute can
>   be called only by fully trusted code; it does not have to demand
>   specific permissions. It cannot be called by partially trusted code.

Comment: Doing this on the method call itself did not remove the code analysis warning. When I used it as an assembly attribute, the warnings were removed. The assembly attribute works better for me because I had about 45 of these warnings [assembly: SecurityCriticalAttribute]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `[PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]`.